# public List<Model> loadInBackground() method in android does not get data from jSon Array

Tags: java, android, json

I am developing an application using android and i'm trying to get the jSon Array displayed in Listfragment using the loadInBackground() method below in my  DataListLoader class:

```
class DataListLoader extends AsyncTaskLoader<List<Model>> {
List<Model> mModels;
String jsonString;
String name = "Daniel Nyerere", phone = "0652400670";

public DataListLoader(Context context) {
    super(context);
    loadInBackground();
}



public List<Model> loadInBackground() {
    // You should perform the heavy task of getting data from
    // Internet or database or other source
    // Here, we are generating some Sample data
    // Create corresponding array of entries and load with data.
    final List<Model> entries = new ArrayList<Model>(50);
    StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(
            Request.Method.GET, "http://10.0.2.2/webapp/json_get_data.php", new Response.Listener<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {
            if (response.trim().contains("server_response")) {
                jsonString = response.toString();
                try {
                    JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(jsonString);
                    JSONArray jsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("server_response");
                    int count = 0;

                    while (count < jsonArray.length()) {
                        JSONObject jo = jsonArray.getJSONObject(count);
                        name = jo.getString("name");
                        phone = jo.getString("user_phone");
                        entries.add(new Model(name, phone));
                        System.out.println("DATA FROM JSON ARRAY: " + name + " " + phone);
                        count++;
                        return;
                    }
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

        }
    });
    RequestQueue requestQueue = VolleySingleton.getInstance().getRequestQueue();
    requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
    entries.add(new Model(name, phone));
    return entries;
}
```

But when i try to run it the data from System.out.println("DATA ENTRIES: "+entries); comes as null list ,so no data get displayed in the fragment activity . Anyone who can help me to fix it so that i get data from json because it consume me a lot of time

Comment: Are u try to check your json array length?

Comment: No ,i want to take the data from array and display it in listfragment by passing it to the Model class through the List

Comment: You didn't understand me... Are you check that answer from the server is correct? What is array length?

Comment: I checked the length so that i could use it to check the data then pass it through the loop

Comment: Oh, how many elements jsonArray contains? Just if your loop doesn't work then the list size will be 0.

Comment: The json array contains three elements rows : Daniel Nyerere 0652400670
 Daniel Nyerere 0754897505
Daniel Nyerere 0755000000 ,Those get displayed when outputing them from the loop

Comment: Are u just know it? Or did you checked it in the console output?

Comment: Add this string in the loop `Log.d("test", "Count: " + count); And see to it posted in the LogCat

Comment: Just I didn't see problems in your code. So maybe, the problem in the server answer

Comment: Yes i checked it from System.out.println("DATA FROM JSON ARRAY: " + name + " " + phone); as shown in the code

Comment: I didn't see it) Is your list length 0? Or is the list pointer null?

Comment: If first then all is right because your code in `loadInBackground` and code in `onResponse` will call in different time

Comment: You need to put the list creation and the output in `onResponse` method

Comment: Yes the List comes as null ,The problem i see from my code is the data from the loop is not seen by the List to be added as entries and then get returned ,can you help me to fix so that the data in jSon can be seen in the List

Comment: Your try to add the data to the list that can already not exist at this moment

Comment: Then how can i fix it in this case

Comment: Move all code in your callback (`onResponse`)

Comment: Can you try to write it to me the sample?

Comment: What will i return

Comment: I posted your code with comment to you can understand how to fix your bug

Answer (score 0):

```
//You can call it in UI thread
final List<Model> entries = new ArrayList<Model>(5);
    StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(
            Request.Method.GET, "http://10.0.2.2/webapp/json_get_data.php", new Response.Listener<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {
            //you need to update the `ListView` content here
            //If you need you can create new thread here too e.g. using AsyncTask
        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

        }
    });
RequestQueue requestQueue = VolleySingleton.getInstance().getRequestQueue();
requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
```

Comment: I have tried it but the problem comes with the entries that are returned becomes null

Comment: Post your fixed code. Just I cannot write a code from mobile